# RSpec path helper unavaliable in services/form_objects specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rspec-rails 3.5.2 and Rails 5.0.1 (well, upgrading to it... RSpec used to be 3.4.2 and Rails 4.2.7.1). In my services/form_objects specs I get the

```
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `company_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000012872a28>:0x000000116f8db0>
   Did you mean?  company_url
```

in a lot of tests - do You know what may cause such behaviour?
PS I do not have 'type: :foobar' in my services/form_objects specs, but changing it to for example :controller does not resolve issue.

I am also using `rails-controller-testing`, not sure if it is relevant.

Already tried adding `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`  to my specs_helper but it does not work.

Comment: I think it's related to this issue - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1644 . The possible solutions are mentioned there

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to post the answer here instead of just being in the comment since somebody might come across it:

It's related with this [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1644) where there is a conflict with the gem `rails-controller-testing`. Read the detailed discussion on Github.

Comment: unfortunately proposed answers does not work for me, Still some test throw this error... even some controller specs! I have no idea what's up with it.